# Problema para enviar datos de un JFrame a otro

Tags: java, jframe

Tengo que crear un dashboard que me cuente la cantidad de personas que doy de alta pero no logro obtener el size() de mi linkedList donde guardo las personas desde el jFrame del dashboard. Intenté hacer un método para trasladarlo pero aún así no funciona.

```
package PersonaMetodos;


public class Metodos {

    static LinkedList <Persona> personas = new LinkedList<Persona>();
    LinkedList <Vehiculo> vehiculos = new LinkedList<Vehiculo>();
    LinkedList <Barco> barcos = new LinkedList<Barco>();
    LinkedList <Avion> aviones = new LinkedList<Avion>();
    
    public void guardar(Persona unaPersona) {
        personas.add(unaPersona);
    }
    
    public void guardar(Vehiculo unVehiculo) {
        vehiculos.add(unVehiculo);
    }
    
    public void guardar(Barco unBarco) {
        barcos.add(unBarco);
    }
    
    public void guardar(Avion unAvion) {
        aviones.add(unAvion);
    }
    
    //Generar archivo de texto para guardar una persona
    public void guardarArchivo(Persona persona) {
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Personas.txt", true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            pw.print(persona.getId());
            pw.print("|" + persona.getNombre());
            pw.print("|" + persona.getApellido());
            pw.print("|" + persona.getDptoResidencia());
            pw.print("|" + persona.getCantHijos());
            pw.print("|" + persona.getFechaNacimiento());
            pw.print("\n");
            pw.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
    
    //Generar archivo de texto para guardar un vehículo
    public void guardarVehiculo(Vehiculo vehiculo) {
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Vehículos.txt", true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            pw.print(vehiculo.getIdDueño());
            pw.print("|" + vehiculo.getIdVehiculo());
            pw.print("|" + vehiculo.getNombre());
            pw.print("|" + vehiculo.getColor());
            pw.print("\n");
            pw.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
    
    //Generar archivo de texto para guardar un barco
        public void guardarBarco(Barco barco) {
            try {
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Barcos.txt", true);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
                pw.print(barco.getIdDueño());
                pw.print("|" + barco.getIdVehiculo());
                pw.print("|" + barco.getNombre());
                pw.print("|" + barco.getColor());
                pw.print("|" + barco.getEslora());
                pw.print("|" + barco.getManga());
                pw.print("\n");
                pw.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        }
    
    //Generar archivo de texto para guardar un avión
            public void guardarAvion(Avion avion) {
                try {
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Aviones.txt", true);
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
                    pw.print(avion.getIdDueño());
                    pw.print("|" + avion.getIdVehiculo());
                    pw.print("|" + avion.getNombre());
                    pw.print("|" + avion.getColor());
                    pw.print("|" + avion.getLongitud());
                    pw.print("|" + avion.getCantPasajeros());
                    pw.print("\n");
                    pw.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                }
            }
            
    public int cantidadPersonas() {
        return personas.size(); 
    }
                
}   


package ventanaInicio;


public class Dashboard extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Dashboard frame = new Dashboard();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    

package ventanaInicio;

public class VentanaInicio extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField_3;
    private JTextField textField_4;
    private JTextField textField_5;
    
    //Acá escribí
    Persona persona = new Persona();
    Metodos metodos = new Metodos();
    private JTextField textField_6;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    VentanaInicio frame = new VentanaInicio();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public VentanaInicio() {
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 487);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(new Color(204, 204, 255));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("ID:");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 74, 49, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
        
        JLabel lblNombre = new JLabel("Nombre:");
        lblNombre.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblNombre.setBounds(10, 108, 58, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNombre);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1_1 = new JLabel("Apellido:");
        lblNewLabel_1_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblNewLabel_1_1.setBounds(10, 140, 58, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1_1);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1_1_1 = new JLabel("Departamento de residencia:");
        lblNewLabel_1_1_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblNewLabel_1_1_1.setBounds(10, 172, 174, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1_1_1);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1_1_1_1 = new JLabel("Cantidad de hijos:");
        lblNewLabel_1_1_1_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblNewLabel_1_1_1_1.setBounds(10, 206, 126, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1_1_1_1);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1_1_1_1_1 = new JLabel("Fecha de nacimiento:");
        lblNewLabel_1_1_1_1_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblNewLabel_1_1_1_1_1.setBounds(10, 240, 174, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1_1_1_1_1);
        
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(241, 65, 96, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        
        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.setBounds(241, 102, 96, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_1);
        
        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setColumns(10);
        textField_2.setBounds(241, 134, 96, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_2);
        
        textField_3 = new JTextField();
        textField_3.setColumns(10);
        textField_3.setBounds(241, 166, 96, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_3);
        
        textField_4 = new JTextField();
        textField_4.setColumns(10);
        textField_4.setBounds(241, 200, 96, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_4);
        
        textField_5 = new JTextField();
        textField_5.setColumns(10);
        textField_5.setBounds(241, 234, 96, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_5);
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Guardar");
        btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                
                String id = textField.getText();
                String nombre = textField_1.getText();
                String apellido = textField_2.getText();
                String dptoResidencia = textField_3.getText();
                String cantHijos = textField_4.getText();
                String fechaNacimiento = textField_5.getText();
                
                persona.setId(id);
                persona.setNombre(nombre);
                persona.setApellido(apellido);
                persona.setDptoResidencia(dptoResidencia);
                persona.setCantHijos(cantHijos);
                persona.setFechaNacimiento(fechaNacimiento);
                
                metodos.guardar(persona);
                metodos.guardarArchivo(persona);
                System.out.println(metodos.cantidadPersonas());
                
                textField_6.setText("id: " + id + "/ nombre: " + nombre + "/ apellido: " + apellido + "/ d.Residencia: " + dptoResidencia + "/ c.Hijos: " + cantHijos + "/ f.Nacimiento: " + fechaNacimiento);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro exitoso");
                
                textField.setText("");
                textField_1.setText("");
                textField_2.setText("");
                textField_3.setText("");
                textField_4.setText("");
                textField_5.setText("");
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(248, 405, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Atr\u00E1s");
        btnNewButton_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                //this.dispose();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(10, 405, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Alta de personas.");
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Semibold", Font.BOLD, 30));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(10, 11, 327, 43);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);
        
        textField_6 = new JTextField();
        textField_6.setBounds(10, 288, 327, 94);
        contentPane.add(textField_6);
        textField_6.setColumns(10);
    }
}
```

Básicamente necesitaría que el size del linkedList personas quede guardado en algún lado para así trasladarlo al dashboard y que a medida que agrego una persona el dashboard se actualice con la cantidad de personas ingresadas al proyecto. No sé si la manera correcta de hacerlo es mediante el linkedlist.size() o debería buscar otra forma.

Comment: Intentaste con .getSize?

Comment: @G.Ortega sí intenté y en el JFrame donde instancio las personas (VentanaInicio) funciona correctamente pero a la hora de visualizarlo en el JFrame del dashboard me marca el size como 0

Comment: Debes establecer clara y consistentemente una relación directa o indirecta entre Dashboard y Metodos. A menos que através de métodos intermediarios y visibilidad expongas `size()` una buena opción es implementar un [Patrón Observador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_\(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o\)).